# Multiple Selection in Custom Ribbon Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, ribbon-control, ribbonx

Is there a way to incorporate multiple selection in Custom Ribbon without having to reopen the drop down every time I select an option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the drop down on Quick Access Toolbar, More Commands.... and add commands to show on the ribbon.

Hope this help.